# Assigning default value to Autocomplete in MaterialUI and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to display default value to my Autocomplete TextField component from Material UI in React.js. A pre-populated value that is automatically loaded from the users' profile and that can be changed with another one from the list.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export const ComboBox =() => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" defaultValue="The Godfather" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 } 
]
```

I only see the input field with the label on it. 
defaultValue is listed as an API of both TextField and Autocomplete and I also tried to move it directly under Autocomplete. Still not working.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

your `defaultValue` of `<AutoComplete />` should have the same format as your `options`, the `getOptionLabel()` is used to form the label even from your `defaultValue`.

in your code `title` property of the string is `undefined`, so nothing is shown.

this code should work fine:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={top100Films}
    defaultValue={{ title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 }}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" defaultValue="The Godfather" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Comment: OK. I understand what you mean. Thank you. This works as intended!

Comment: and ho do i get the default value?

Comment: well, here you should make your own choice

Comment: what if I don't have the options yet? because the options will come asynchronously from the API request made when typing in autocomplete

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing checkout https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `defaultValue` option like this:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={top100Films}
    defaultValue={ top100Films[0] }
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" defaultValue="The Godfather" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Comment: This does assign the value but it is still not rendering it on the screen. It still initially displaying the label.

Comment: What do you mean by "still displaying the label"? Please create a working example in https://codesandbox.io

Comment: I want it to look like this initially: https://imgur.com/a/0v15c0C . This is what it defaults to : https://imgur.com/D6TINi4

Comment: If you want the value of `12 Angry Men` to be available you should have it in the `options`, and it's not there currently. You can add it inside, and than use it inside the `defaultValue`.

Comment: thanks for the help Dekel. the solution above is what i was looking for exactly.

Comment: Not sure if you even checked my solution, it's actually exactly the same code.

Comment: What if the array is passed `EMPTY` it generate error ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use **multiple** so you should set defaultValue in list like blow

```
<Autocomplete multiple id="tags-standard" options={categoryList}
    defaultValue={[{ title: "cat1", id: 1 }, { title: "cat2", id: 2 }]}

    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} variant="standard" label="Category" />
    )}
    onChange={handleCategory}
                            
    />
```

Comment: defaultValue={[value[0]]} worked for me, thanks